# Figuring out high side N channel MOSFET switching

Tags: mosfet, high-side

I'd like to build a high side N channel MOSFET as I want to make a BLDC ESC. I need one on the high side and one on the low side so I can change the polarity.

I thought N channel MOSFETs were the best choice so I bought some IFRB3207.

The low side switch works fine but this schematic for the high side doesn't work:

[image: schematic of bootstrap circuit]

The load remains on even when the gate is at ground.

I then tested this without the capacitors or diodes here:

[image]

For some reason, the LED is on even though the gate is at gnd and the source is at +5V. For an N channel MOSFET, I thought the gate had to be 5V above the source. In this case, it is 5V below.

Here's the circuit on a breadboard.  The orange wire was connected to ground and the blue to +5V.  They were disconnected here so the LED didn't blind the camera:

[image]

Comment: "For some reason, the LED is on even though the gate is at gnd and the source is at +5V." – In your schematic, the gate is at GND and the _drain_ is at 5 V. The source is connected to the load, so it should be at GND, meaning that Vgs is 0 V here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your source and drain swapped. If we look at the datasheet accessed [here](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/196/Infineon_IRFS3207Z_DataSheet_v01_01_EN-3363247.pdf)

[image]

You can see the swap. The MOSFET will always conduct with this wiring due to the internal diode. (thanks Chris)

Comment: "The MOSFET will be always on with this wiring" ...due to the internal body diode always being forward biased.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the issue but it does seem counter intuitive to have the power supply plugged into the drain and the output into the source.

Comment: It is confusing, but the names are based on the source and drain of electrons rather than conventional current.